# Sending email after a database column is updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005, email

I have a web app for a client built in C# .Net 3.5. The web app does lots of things and there is one part where I send some data via an asychronous web request to do some processing on the database. This can take anywhere from 5 to 60 minutes.

I then created a SQL trigger that when the column in the database that uses the Database Mail to send mail (via msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail).

This works fine, but our client forbids us to send mail from the database server.

Anyone have an alternative to this?

Comment: And server aside, they should forbid you from sending e-mail from a trigger. Especially if it means you have to handle multi-row updates where you have to send those e-mails in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an Email table containing all of the fields you need for your emails.  Add a record for each email you need to send given your processing.

Next, write a Windows service that pings that database for new email records at a regular interval.  If found, generate your emails and send them from your application tier.  Don't forget to have a boolean or similar mechanism indicating that the email has been sent so that it doesn't get picked up more than once.

Answer (score 2):

My coder sense smells something fishy going on, but what keeps you from updating another table that you check on a timed interval with your application server? And have the application server send the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Even a column on the Email table for "SendStatus" that can be "ReadyForSend", "Sent", "Error" or something is better than the trigger plan.  And then some sort of scheduled task that looks for items in the proper state to be sent.

Keep in mind the poor guy who has to figure out how this all works in 6 months to a year when you may or may not be on the project any longer.